# Filling up entire open address harsh table with double hashing function

Tags: hashtable, double-hashing

Can double hashing able to fill-up all the entries inside a hash table in open address hashing that based on a prime number?

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, yes. If the hash table has `n` buckets, just insert `n` elements.

The double-hashing probe sequence must be designed so that it hits every bucket (if it doesn't, that would be a deficiency in the scheme). In particular, this means that the second hash function must never evaluate to 0 mod n, which can be guaranteed by forcing it to 1 if it would otherwise be 0.

Comment: What is the worse case complexity of open addressing hash? Is it Θ(n) or O(n)?